# Acknowledging a comment with an upvote

Tags: discussion, comments

There are many a time where I will simply upvote a comment to give some kind of assurance to the poster that I have read their comment. I'm sure I'm not the only person that does this.

**Q:** Does this affect anything statistically? Am I actively going against the system in any kind of way?

Comment: Well, it should be used to indicate that the comment is somehow important in relation to the post. That you've been reading it doesn't necessarily fall into tha category.

Comment: To my mind, you're _encouraged_ to up vote comments when they're helpful ('_this comment adds something useful to the post_'), like the questions and answers. If you read the comment, that doesn't necessarily mean it was helpful. But still, you _can_ up vote any comment you want.

Comment: I have no dispute about what the upvote functionality is actually there for - and I also acknowledge that in this context I'm not really using it properly. But I want to know if there are any _consequences_ of this, if I'm skewing some statistics, or generally being a bad influence etc...

Comment: As far as I know, the only thing this does is ensure the comment remains visible once the list of comments becomes too long to show all of them. The most up-voted comments remain visible while the others are collapsed. Since not everyone will click the link to show all comments, its better to up vote ones that are more important for others to see.

Comment: I would rather see `+12 <comment>` than 12 separate comments, in any case.

Comment: The [pundit badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) is based on comment upvotes.  But if yours is the only upvote, you won't affect the comment author's badge progress.

Comment: i occasionally upchuck rather than upvote, but i figure it's accomplishing about the same thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Am I actively going against the system in any kind of way?

Yes, this has a few minor effects on how the comments are treated.  In cases where comment discussion get long and you see the "show N more comments" comments with better scores (upvotes) are given preference.  From the [MSE How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/280467):

> - When there are many comments on a post, some comments are hidden when the page loads, and there is a button to “show N more comments”. The comments with the fewest upvotes are hidden first. The threshold depends on the number of comments on the post and on the number of answers on the page.

So an upvoted but relatively useless comment could appear in the uncollapsed list of comments.  If it had not been upvoted it might have been hidden by default, and a more relevant comment would possibly have appeared instead.

Additionally, comments can be automatically deleted with comment flags without moderator intervention in specific situations.  Upvotes on comments can make it more difficult for the system to auto delete a comment without moderator action.  (A lone "I've read this comment" upvote won't affect this)

> - If a comment is flagged by three users, it will be auto-soft-deleted. There is no penalty for this. Flagged comments will be surfaced to moderators, so if you have a problem with a comment, flag it.
> - Comments with upvotes require more flags to be deleted without moderator intervention: 1 more flag per 3 votes above 3 (i.e. number of flags = 3 + score/3).

I'd encourage you to upvote only comments you actually feel are worth attention and saving.  But ultimately it's not a huge deal because comments aren't judged with the same rigor as posts.

Comment: Do you know if upvotes affect how "special" comments can be deleted with a single flag? Anyone can delete "What have you tried?" comments with 1 flag normally, for example.

Comment: @Laurel no idea.  I'm pretty sure the exact details of the keywords/patterns and the workings are secret.  I would image that upvotes do not affect "special" comments (like ones that contain blacklisted content).