# New Styles? New shade of green for accepted answers? It's not easy... being green

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, accessibility

Stack Overflow just got updated with some new styles. This includes a new, more vibrant shade of green for accepted answers, and questions with existing answers are now denoted by only a square:

[image]

There have also been some other changes, like the block quote background:

[image]

Code formatting has also apparently changed fonts, but I can't see any difference.

Is there anyplace that has mentioned this update either as a planned update or as an *ex post facto* announcement?

It'd be great to have an official post to talk about this/give feedback, especially since not everyone was in favor of the initial changes (the lack of contrast in quotes, the distracting vibrancy of the green, the lack of compliance with 1.4.1 of WCAG - Use of Color, *et cetera*).

Comment: -1, There  are no free hand circles. I don't know where to look

Comment: @BhargavRao I flagged your comment as offensive; There are no actual downvotes on this post.

Comment: And so Web 3.0 begins. Needs more pastel!

Comment: Updated with freehand circles

Comment: I don't like that green.. At least on my screen it's too aggressive..

Comment: Meta best seller: 50 shades of green ...

Comment: Let's just wait and see what this CSS change broke, we know it's inevitable.

Comment: @CubeJockey Depending on who you ask, it broke readability of [quotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321393/2756409).

Comment: +1 for discussion about colors, not about acceptance of color! That box stands out too much now.

Comment: I actually like the new design, looks better now.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Personally I like the new green as well.

Comment: I like it! Now we just need to [get rid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278354/favorite-tag-highlighting) of that ugly yellowish background.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the color update. We're monitoring feedback from everyone and will make a post later. This update is part of a massive work on our part to reduce the number of colors as well as reduce our bandwidth on CSS. So far we've gone from about 110 grays to 15 with this update. We will be making changes to fix bugs though.

Comment: Upon each and every small UI change in SO an obligatory Meta will always follow with a lot whining/free hand circles and up votes...

Comment: Like all UI changes, I anticipate hating it for several days and then slowly forgetting that it was ever different.

Comment: Uh oh.  That "new" green is showing up in other places now, in the profile summary, answers, questions, and favorites.

Comment: @Don'tPanic on day to day basis Meta is about - A lot of whining/free hand circles and mob **downvoting**. Unless it's a UI change

Comment: One green to rule them all. Except that other, lighter green. Okay, so two greens to rule them all.

Comment: @PetahChristian Yes, that's most likely intentional. The color indicates the same thing in each location: existence of answers, and existence of accepted answers.

Comment: @Hynes Glad to know you guys are watching for it, but again, just a simple meta post somewhere saying "hey, we're consolidating our color palettes, look for ongoing changes and post bugs here as answers!" would be great :-) \*hint hint\*

Comment: @DavidArenburg Hey now, don't give anyone any ideas.

Comment: @NickCraver The other, lighter green should rule.

Comment: @Hynes Thanks for noticing? It's hard *not* to notice. The colors have a lot to do with the overall look of a site. If you're trying to do branding, having a consistent color palette is a must.

Comment: The lack of contrast in quotes is a bug that's being fixed in a few moments.

Comment: A change in greenery on 4/20? Well played, SE!

Comment: Grey on green looks [absolutely terrible now](http://i.imgur.com/IkPI0zv.png) in the badge/privilege trackers @Hynes - hovering amplifies the effect, too

Comment: @Rob Thanks for letting me know. I'll take a look. Is this on SO or Meta.SO?

Comment: @Hynes On SO - though I've just seen a post reporting the same issue [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321420/forgotten-element-at-new-color-theme)

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Great! Thanks

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Not sure if we'll get rid of the yellow background (right now), but in the next production build it will be lighter.

Comment: @Hynes It was worth a shot.. I have a UserScript right now that does it for me. Looks really good with the new colors.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/rLn0p.png

Comment: I love the new colors. They look great.

Comment: New font style for code also looks good

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I really like those duplicate markers you have there! (do you have a link you can share? ^^)

Comment: @poke you can browse some of the published scripts [here](http://stackapps.com/) :)

Comment: The colour highlighting for 'favourite' tagged questions is .. well, basically invisible now. Really have to strain my eyes to see any difference between the white and yellow

Comment: @PaulG It's likely hard to see on monitors with poor contrast ratios. I'm curious, what monitor do you have? it's clearly visible to me. Of course, eyesight could factor in, too.

Comment: @poke, what you're seeing isn't duplicate question markers, those are questions with a favorited tag, I couldn't stand the yellowish color.  It's part of [SOX](http://github.com/soscripted/sox), that particular feature is still under development, FYI. :)

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I was actually referring to those two questions with the yellow “duplicate” marker instead of the text-only “[duplicate]”. But thanks, that project looks interesting!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

#### Update 04/21/2016

We appreciate everyone's feedback so far. The design team spent some time today reviewing complaints surrounding the green's brightness and the number of green backgrounds. Here are two updates we're making:

1. **We're changing the green's hue to a cooler, bluer green.** This will dull some of the green's brightness. Here's a comparison of the previous greens to the newer greens:
   [image: New Greens!]
2. **We've removed the faint background-color behind answered questions, going instead with a one-pixel border treatment.** This reserves background colors only for accepted answers. Throughout the Stack Exchange network, the only thing that changes for answered questions is the status color changes from black to green. While Stack Overflow is a part of the Stack Exchange network, it also is unique and can be treated differently. We feel this solution allows a person to understand quickly what hasn't been answered, what has been answered, and what has an accepted answer. This also reduces the colors in the question list and makes it less overwhelming.

As an aside, we are continuing to look at the favorite question highlighting. We understand that many have complained about the yellow background and some have offered some interesting solutions on Meta Stack Exchange. We hope to have an update for this in the near-future.

---

For a while the product team has known that we needed to consolidate our UI to make sure we were providing a more consistent UI and UX experience. Yet it was always more of a "nice-to-have" than a must-have. Over the last few months we've started extending the Stack Overflow UI in new (and exciting!) ways with Documentation, Jobs, Developer Story, and Teams. These extensions nudged a consolidated UI library to the forefront.

Yet what really pushed this was growth of our CSS to over 600 kB. So a few weeks ago we began to consolidate and reduce repetition. This update completes the last of the "low-hanging" fruits. So far we've reduced the raw CSS by almost 150 kB. In particular it has minimized variation among main colors by almost 50 colors each. We're still planning to reduce further, because performance is so important to us.

In addition to performance gains, consolidating the CSS was an opportunity to finally make a few updates to Stack Overflow that match the new branding that we rolled out last summer.

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new green overlords.

Comment: This feels so...right.  Tell the devs on this work that they really did a good job.

Comment: Has the yellow background been changed too, or have I just gone mad? I swear it wasn't always so upsetting. Something like #FFF8E7 is a lot less tear inducive, and it works fine for the "featured" box too. I swear I've never disliked a color so much. (Hint: me going mad is entirely plausible.)

Comment: @Veedrac Which yellow background are you referring to?

Comment: I thoroughly dislike having my attention yanked to the bright green boxes. Consolidating styles is all well and good, but this particular change seems unnecessarily disruptive. Please reduce the contrast to something which isn't actively distracting. (Speaking frankly, as a user I don't actually care about your branding; I just want the site to be nice to use. Any branding that makes the site worse should perhaps be called into question.)

Comment: Forget the branding, @phils. Focus on the *less CSS*. Faster green is better green.

Comment: @TylerH The one covering most of your screenshot to represent posts with favorited tags.

Comment: @Veedrac Looks like it's already been muted from `#fff8dc` to `#fdfaee`.

Comment: Did you check the color contrast against WCAG AA because to me it looks like the dark green on light green is not compliant.

Comment: Is the code formatting now in Consolas? It's my favorite font. I use it everywhere.

Comment: @TylerH The yellow color is pus-yellow in your screenshot. I'll have to agree it doesn't fit with the new green.

Comment: Forgive my pendantry, but a lower-case `b` indicates a bit, and an uppercase `B` indicates a byte. You probably meant to use `kB`.

Comment: @Flimm hah, don't you know of SE's efficiency! They're **clearly** upset about the css *bloated* to 600kb+! not kB! kB is for the "Common as muck!" folk! :)

Comment: @Flimm [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/394/)...

Comment: @cst1992 Per my comment to Veedrac, they already adjusted the yellow to a different shade.

Comment: The new yellow is better, and it does resolve the "halo" effect around the bright green box. Thanks! Any possibility of the accepted answer green being slightly tweaked to be less "bright?" That answer box is still much more prominent than any other element on the page.

Comment: The new yellow (#fdfaee) is too light. My eyes struggle to see the difference between the white and yellow at anything much lighter than #fdfaea

Comment: _We've removed the faint background-color behind answered questions, going instead with a 1px border treatment._ A change in color is sufficient. I don't need a box around it as well. Has no inherent semantic meaning either.

Comment: @j08691 The background-color on accepted answer doesn't have inherent semantic meaning either. All of these have learned meaning. We did explore eliminating the box completely, but didn't feel strong enough about it right now to change it. We may revisit it again after people have more time to interact with it.

Comment: Thank you thank you *thank you* for removing the background color on answered questions. I'd love to see that border removed as well (the real info being shared with the viewer is given by the number), but I'll take each victory as it comes.

Comment: please make it like it was before. i don't have any good reasons; i just don't like change and am not willing to even give my mind a chance to adjust over the next few days. i want it fixed NOW, dammit!

Comment: The site now doesn't have enough pastel! :(

Comment: *As an aside, we are continuing to look at the favorite question highlighting. We understand that many have complained about the yellow background and some have offered some interesting solutions on Meta.SE. We hope to have an update for this in the near-future.*  <-- **just made my day**

Comment: You accidentally a feature request, would you like to mark [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272075) status-completed?

Comment: @Meta I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The feature request is to include green indicator of accepted answer in Related column. As my answer there shows, this has been done now.

Comment: @Meta You can edit that tag into the question yourself FYI

Comment: @Meta Oh, nevermind... you used to be able to. Looks like they've changed that now :-(

Comment: Going with the outlined unanswered is much, much better than the faded green box. It will still take getting used to, but much better, thanks.

Comment: [Why are the green boxes removed for accepted answers when using `is:a`?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa) Very inconvenient.

Comment: @Pang You should post a question tagged with `bug` about that so that it can receive individual attention.

Comment: Maybe you can also take this time to remove duplicate definitions or overlapping definitions. I have noticed several before and from just glancing I noticed the twin definitions for `.question-summary`, and three definitions for `#footer`, two for `.topbar`, two for `.topbar .topbar-wrapper`, two for `.topbar .topbar-icon` etc. etc. If the goal is to reduce bandwidth, then reducing the amount of duplication will help as well! :D

Comment: [New question posted here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322108) concerning *"Why are the green boxes removed for accepted answers when using is:a? Very inconvenient."*.

Answer (score 33):

I was puzzled why the white on green text boxes were very distracting, drawing my focus from other text elements on the page, while the other (white on blue or orange) text boxes weren't contributing to any such distraction.

After some quick searching, I found out that [the human eyeball is most sensitive to green light, less to red and least to blue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596243/4151918). This is reflected in [the luminosity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function):

> Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B
>
> **green light contributes the most to the intensity perceived by humans**, and blue light the least.

I have no familiarity with this color spectrum sensitivity math. Perhaps one of the many talented designers at Stack Overflow who understands this could find a more optimum shade of green which would be less disruptive while trying to read the question titles!

According to the range of comments, perhaps it would help to shift the new color consensus from the `Vibrant; Vivid; Distracting; Aggressive; Weird; Clashes` end of the spectrum, moving it closer to the `Great; Right; Nice` side.

Comment: I learned something. Thanks :)

Comment: A more pastel version of the same green would be less jarring I think. This would reduce the contrast between accepted/non-accepted answers, but I don't think it would be a problem given the extreme contrast introduced by the latest change.

Comment: @MarkRansom: But what if we *want* contrast between accepted and non-accepted answers? That's what I like most about the change: I can easily tell the difference between empty questions, possibly full questions, and finished questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Distinguishing between the different states is fine, but should accepted questions be most noticeable? Aren't unanswered or non-accepted questions the ones that need more notice?

Comment: @PetahChristian: Accepted questions have *always* been the most noticeable. The main thing that's changed is the ability to easily tell the difference between unanswerd and answered-but-not-accepted.

Comment: @NicolBolas The main thing that changed is the colors.  We *already* were able easily distinguish between unanswered (black 0 on white background) and answered but unaccepted (white number on olive background). Accepted questions weren't more noticeable than unaccepted questions, since they (had a different foreground color, but) both had used an identical olive background (to show that both had answers).

Comment: @NicolBolas it's a balancing act. I think you can indicate the difference WITHOUT SHOUTING IT OUT. I also think there's merit in reversing the emphasis so that the empty questions stand out while the accepted answers are muted, but that clashes with the expectation that an absence of color corresponds to an absence of answers.

Comment: @MarkRansom It also clashes with the expectation that people come here for good answers. Answerers are the minority on the site; it's targeted for people who come seeking knowledge.

Comment: @TylerH the people who come for answers go directly to a question, they don't peruse the front page. Or if they do, it's only to find the Search button.

Comment: @MarkRansom The first time they come to the site, yes, but a major effort of the site (like any site) is geared toward passing traffic, e.g. trapping the user's interest and keeping them here. Even the search results use the same colors and styles.