# Syntax highlighting for strings is hard to see now

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, syntax-highlighting

Many of the recent color changes to Stack Overflow have been welcome, but I find it frustrating that the syntax highlighting no longer colors strings and numbers in an easily identifiable color.

I can't tell the difference between `#4a1c21` (CSS `.str`, `.lit`) and `#181a1c` (CSS `.pln`) with any reliability when they are just text colors. They both look "kind of black" to me.

I can tell the difference with [big](http://paletton.com/#uid=15z0u0kjU9Hc7hVeYbIoj72tN4b) [squares](http://paletton.com/#uid=13-0u0k4X5q4Fk54VdCd34ZjF4O), but not text foreground.

There are lots of javascript examples [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5731193/241211) It's hardest (for me) to tell the difference on the really short strings (`''`, `'.'`). Even if I'm wrong and the colors haven't changed recently, it'd still be nice to have something a *little* brighter.

Comment: Do you have a URL example I could refer to?

Comment: Admittedly, [my own choice of colours](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html) is much brighter, but I agree that strings are hard to distinguish and to me, appear as black.

Comment: I cannot tell the difference either, or... I'm just getting old :(

Comment: So now we have to figure out if OP's syntax is right or not now. What used to be black or blue, is now "green"? What next, "shades of pink" for the ladies? hehe Edit: I spoke too soon, there is one, the tag for [`status-completed`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: it is the new [50 shades of green](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/new-styles-new-shade-of-green-for-accepted-answers-its-not-easy-being-gree#comment335174_321413)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Shows that people have opinions about colors. :D

Comment: I like change, but I do think that something that affects the site in such a drastic way really should be consulted a bit more or perhaps even voted on before being changed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. You are correct that the colors have very low contrast between each other. I've spent some time last night and this morning adjusting the colors. These colors will be updated with the next production build.

---

#### Update

Based on the comments, I've made some color adjustments. I've dulled the purple brightness and reverted `tag` to maroon versus purple. You can preview these changes compared to the previous colors below. These changes are now live.

[image: Before/After Syntax]

Comment: The XML syntax highlighting went from red to blue. Was that intended? (I'm talking about the color of the XML tags)

Comment: Not to mention HTML form code that we now see as being 2 shades of blue. Wasn't there some announcement that I missed on this and to vote on it or not? *lol*

Comment: These new colors feel like they're straight outta Sesame Street.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes. The colors are based on the default prettyprint colors. Previously tags (`.tag`) were the same color as literal values (`.lit`), but were too hard to differentiate from plain text.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Two shades of blue? There's only one blue color within the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Hynes Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/36869738/  unless that has yet to propagate to your account.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see a purple and a blue there. Both colors were used before but they were both rather dark and could have been mistaken for a dark gray. Are you asking for the brightness to be dulled on those colors?

Comment: @Hynes I think our monitors aren't set at the same gamma rate *lol* because I see `<form` being as #2609E2 and `action` shows as #1086DF taken from Eyedropper. So the first is like a navy and the other like an Olympic blue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're correct. One is purple (`#2609E2 `) and the other is blue (`#1086DF`)

Comment: `#2609E2` is hardly purple. Indigo at most. Anyway, this is a really nice change.

Comment: @Hynes I guess it's just me then. Probably because I'm on a laptop at 1280 and you/others on super high definition widescreens(?). I guess I'll just have to live with it then and get used to it, which stands to take about 2-3 months like the last CSS update using the lighter white'ish background.

Comment: @AndriyM Oh, so for you too eh? That's it, I'm pulling out my Pantone chart and Photoshop *lol* and I'll get the "true" colors as to what those *really* are.

Comment: @NisseEngström No idea. I copied and pasted some CSS code and that's how it turned out.

Comment: _"Why is (only) `sub` blue?"_ - Is it rendered with `<!-- language: lang-css -->`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've adjusted the purple brightness locally. I'll push the change up to production later.

Comment: @Hynes Ok thanks. *Cheers*

Comment: The new blue on Java code is now very confusing. Some answers have now [3 shades of blue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Use0h.png).  It doesn't make it easy to read. Especially when IDE generally have keywords in "red" (like before).

Comment: @Tunaki I'm only seeing a purple (indigo if you want) and a blue. The darker blue found in the `anyMatch` code is linked, so the link color overrides any code styling. [Previously these were purple and a teal green/blue.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bab1K.png)

Comment: @Hynes Really? I'm pretty sure they were some sort of red. Like HTML and XML tags. Or have I already forgotten all about it? :D

Comment: @Hynes Perhaps you need to add before and after images (just like they show in spam answers). People have already forgotten how it was before

Comment: @BhargavRao Good suggestion. I've updated my post.

Comment: @Hynes, xaml highlight is a mess now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776856/condtional-button-content-in-infragistics-xamgrid-column; (http://i.stack.imgur.com/JGl1g.png) it was pretty good before (very similar to MS Visual Studio editor)

Comment: @Hynes: Nice image update! Except that the CSS part is completely pointless. The Markdown engine renders CSS as (what looks like) `lang-php` by default. To _properly_ render CSS, you need to add `<-- language: lang-css -->` before the code block.

Comment: ... `<!-- language: lang-css -->`

Comment: @Hynes in VBA syntax, green is used in the native editor to indicate a comment so this is extremely confusing. I don't know about other languages but I imagine most people looking at VBA related items aren't going to be a fan of these colours. In fact the previous colours were actually very true to VBA but now are nothing of the sort.

Comment: @Hynes: FWIW if no one else has, I would like to ask for the brightness on the purple and blue colors to be reduced. In fact, I would much prefer plain black text than the day-glo colors in use now, which I find far too bright to read easily.

Comment: Change for change's sake. Has [caused problems](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321826/560648). Next time solicit opinions first please!

Comment: I like how the string color is now green again, but this time nobody brought torches and pitchforks. Hynes, you were just before your time.

Answer (score -3):

If the goal is more contrast. I'm curious what everyone would think of having a white background for the code instead of a gray one.

That should help contrast. It would look something like this:

[image]

Just a thought.

Comment: No popular at all. Interesting. I would have thought that since most of our IDE's have a white background this would be more familiar. By definition it's higher contrast it's why most content websites including StackOverflow have a white background. Well, lesson learned.