# Common CSS going to all sites?

Tags: discussion, design

I want to start off by saying I like the recent changes to the CSS by the design team.  I applaud you all on the nice clean/lean changes.  I especially like the colors, and I am happy we got rid of the background light green on what were "possible answers" and not "accepted answers".  Very nice!

I was curious, as was discussed by an earlier post the point is to reduce the file size and and maybe reuse this css across the other sites?  I was curious why the other sites do not have these same changes, has the global rollout not yet hit and this is why?  Or is this only for SO rather than all SE sites?

Again great job to the team.

Comment: I like the differences in sites

Comment: @Drew - I'm not for it or against it, my point was if they are going to be different that means more CSS.  I thought the original post mentioned that these would be used across multiple SE sites across the network.  Hence my question.

Comment: But once there, it is cached.

Comment: @Drew - Until you flush the cache, now we are talking about a common.css download and a specific.css download.  My question is will the common.css override the specific.css so that the specific.css is no longer needed?  Hence less kb in downloads, and a common theme across the sites?  Again I am in no way favoring one or the other - common is always great but I firmly believe in you can be inconsistent if the inconsistency makes it better.  In other words if specific.css makes some SE site better fine lets keep it.

Comment: I don't believe the changes were made to consolidate colors across the network, but to consolidate colors in the Stack Overflow design because there were too many different ones. Apparently, [Stack Overflow had 63 shades of grey](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/722899864057565186)...

Comment: @animuson - Great that is the sort of answer/comment that makes sense.  So this was across SO not SE.

Comment: @Drew It looks like the colors in syntax highlighting just changed this morning. Now to figure out what's right is right *lol* Edit: Ah, I just found this now http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321731/syntax-highlighting-for-strings-is-hard-to-see-now

Comment: Is it just me or the font size changed? It is a tad smaller now.

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad you're enjoying the updates! Here's my best attempt to answer your questions:

> the point is to reduce the file size and and maybe reuse this css across the other sites?

Yes, reducing our CSS file size is definitely one of our goals. Our primary goal though is to consolidate our UI and UX patterns across Stack Overflow (and the Stack Exchange network). We've accumulated a lot of CSS over the years. Combine that with the launch of new content on SO (Jobs, Teams, Developer Story, Documentation), this problem has only compounded. Keeping styles in sync across teams and products has become extremely hard, if not impossible. For last 6-8 weeks we've started to actively build an internal Pattern Library which will serve as an internal UI and UX documentation guide. By consolidating various highly-specific (but redundant) patterns, we'll be able to reduce our CSS specificity and file size, while creating a more consistent experience.

As we update these various items, we'll roll them out. The recent color update is an example of that. We finally standardized on a set of established color variables and we rolled them out.

> I was curious why the other sites do not have these same changes, has the global rollout not yet hit and this is why?

Most of the updates we've made so far have been across the network. We've updated things buttons and post-tags so that they all have similar hover, active, and disabled behaviors across all communities. This is slow work though. Because of the way the CSS was implemented previously, we need to hand-check every community before we roll out an update.

Our primary focus with the updates right now is with Stack Overflow, but many of the elements on Stack Overflow are on every Stack Exchange community website. So the communities should be updated as we update Stack Overflow. If your question is more in reference to why we haven't rolled out the new answered and accepted-answer styles, this is considered an SO-only modification at the moment. We could roll this change out across the network (and make it the standard style for the questions list). Unfortunately we wouldn't be able to do this until a later time.

Thank you for your patience.

[image: Under Construction]

Comment: This is a solid answer and what I was looking for.  As I said, I'm not for or against it...As I mentioned in the comments, i am a firm believer in keeping it common is great **but** you can be inconsistent if it makes a better product / gives off a better user experience.  The benefit of keeping it common is no matter what community you go to you feel like you are on an SE site because everything is common when it comes to colors, styles, etc.  However, the downside of this is because each community is unique it's hard to keep one set of common colors, styles to match the communities.  Thanks!