# Revert new syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, syntax-highlighting

This morning I've noticed that the syntax highlighting has been *completely* redone. This post will cover C# in particular, but I'm sure there will be similar issues among other languages.

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

Here's how it looks in Visual Studio 2015 with the default theme:

[image]

While in general, most of it is aesthetics, there are two main objective issues I have with the new style:

1. Strings now look like comments. This is *extremely* confusing, and while it may take getting used to, it still completely clashes with the default colour schema of Visual Studio, which I would imagine most developers use.
2. Everything looks like a hyperlink.

   [image]

At the absolute minimum, please allow the syntax highlighting to be configurable, so that we can go back to the original styling.

Comment: I agree that I prefer the old coloring, but when it comes down to it, its not an issue that needs to be "fixed" or customizable, its 100% personal preference, and if the stack exchange developers prefer it this way, its their right to change it.

Comment: @caesay While I agree in general it's a styling decision and personal preference - my point being is that it's very much at odds with the way C# is *typically* displayed (LinqPad, Visual Studio, almost any other online styling). The two issues I pointed out, I feel are objective problems, rather than aesthetic preference.

Comment: @Rob These colors are not *only* used for C#. They're used for every single language that utilizes syntax highlighting on our sites. You can't compare a specific language to how it's "typically rendered" because each language does not get its own styles and customized color schemes on our site.

Comment: @animuson I didn't know that - which makes the issue a bit more difficult then, I suppose. I was under the impression each language *did* have its own style-sheet/colour scheme. That being said, I did find that the code has the `lang-cs` class, which does make it possible to fix edge cases such as these, if people find it is indeed an issue

Comment: I like the brighter colors, but it's probably a mess when the code is not properly parsed (like in Perl with regexes).

Comment: \*ahem\* [(somewhat) relevant link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please)...

Comment: I also agree with this. Old scheme was better.

Comment: Someone needs to say it too: I just love the new colours ❤

Comment: The class colors are just horrible now, not readable at all and a very 'glow-in-the-dark' / radioactive feeling...

Comment: I didn't notice this question and [asked a separate one about comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321860/why-have-strings-within-certain-language-syntax-code-blocks-gone-green) (which I'm now voting to close). I totally agree. Green strings are bad. That light blue feels far too light as well.

Comment: Not a fan of the colour scheme either, but [base16-builder](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-builder) [prettify.js template](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-builder/tree/master/templates/prettify.js) + Stylish for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) / [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Gb/firefox/addon/stylish/) allowed me to apply my IDE theme across stackoverflow.com

Comment: @caesay "if the stack exchange developers prefer it this way, its their right to change it" They have the right for sure, but still they should remember that the site does not exist for their personal satisfaction but the goal is to help programmers all around the world. If I would be a SE developer and I would know that users don't like it I wouldn't do it, however much I personally would like it.

Comment: Let’s face the facts: the syntax highlighting is a slap in the face of the developer anyway, highlighting some arbitrary keywords not matching *any* programming language correctly and then highlighting the other words just based on the case of the first letter, regardless of the semantic. AFAIK, the standard answer to all issues is “we are using that 3rd party highlighter and can’t change anything about it”. For a site addressing *programmers* for several years now, that’s a lame excuse…

Comment: An option for the user to revert back to the old syntax highlighting would be best.

Comment: The colours for `C` are totally off. They're the exact opposite to some of the colours people are used to (like a grey-ish colour for comments, red-ish for preprocessor tokens, green-ish for strings, etc).

Comment: The new color scheme seems to hurt my eyes :/

Comment: Too bad we can't set bounties on Meta -- I would happily sacrifice a fair amount of rep for this change to be reverted.

Comment: @Stijn, good idea, but trying to collectively decide on a color scheme would lead us nowhere I believe (see also: spaces vs. tabs). I'm all for the SE designers making that choice, except that I would like... a better choice?

Comment: I find the SQL highlighting at least much better

Comment: Does SO have any sort of changelog? I'm surprised we keep having Meta posts of "Something changed, what the hell!"

Comment: I use a userscript to use my own coloring which matches the VS theme I use anyway :p

Comment: @CubeJockey, [we have one on the Overmeta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange?answertab=active#tab-top), but it doesn't list that style change for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the link @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: As a someone who doesn't use VS, VS one doesn't really look much better. Besides, all development tools I use (several IDEs, text editors, etc.) have different color schemes anyway. This seems like pretty minor issue to me.

Comment: @Stijn I dislike the colour of this new bikeshed.  Is there somewhere I can go to discuss what colour is should be instead?  That discussion should be highly productive!

Comment: Your point 1 is BS... comments are grey now and strings are green. I don't see how they look like comments any more than in the VS situation.

Comment: The obvious solution is to let every user supply their own color themes (and choose between per-site or network-wide). Although to be frank I don't see my color theme that I've used for almost 8 years now working very well with prettify, given that my theme is Scintilla-based...

Comment: *"default colour schema of Visual Studio"* -- first thing I do when setting up an IDE is change the color scheme. I can't stand a light theme, which most tend to ship with. Look at [how many downloads](https://studiostyl.es/) there are for Visual Studio themes.

Comment: Totally agree (Java). The new syntax coloring sucks. And also the new color scheme in general - it's too light, for my eyes.

Comment: Nooooo, I love the new syntax highlighting, it's *so much eaiser to read!*

Comment: I'm pretty meh about the change, but there is a lot of blue. I'll admit that its different but there's not much to dislike about it.

Comment: @Holger If you'd like to support a change over to highlight.js, there's [Highlight.js: For Real, Please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please).

Comment: I agree the new scheme is much harder to read and differentiate. I've pinged the design team and we'll get this looking better tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not completely sure what the point is you're trying to make, but seems like this discussion was productive: the change has been reverted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on this overwhelming feedback, I reverted the colors from [the other day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321731/syntax-highlighting-for-strings-is-hard-to-see-now), though I did slightly brighten the previous "maroon" color that was being used just to help differentiate from black. The adjustment is small. This is now live on production.

Comment: "Maroon" - My favorite color!!!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321987/1654265

Answer (score 15):

In order to be constructive, I'll try to provide a couple of (subjective) propositions:

The color of types, properties and methods (`#0096e2`) is now very close indeed to the color of unvisited hyperlinks (`#07c`). Reverting only that color to its previous value and / or underlining hyperlinks would solve that problem.

I find myself greatly disturbed by green strings, even though I've actually been using *red* for comments in my IDEs for nearly two decades. I suspect that's because I spend a lot of time in front of my coworkers' screens, and comments are green there. Green strings effectively throw my internal parser off-tracks, and I have to make a conscious effort to register them as strings.

Since the original goal was to differentiate numbers from strings, and since numbers have far less chances of being confused with comments than strings, to me inverting the decision (i.e. making numbers green and strings red) would be enough to solve the problem.

Could the SE design team review these suggestions and decide whether they're worth following?

Comment: The color of links may change as they unify the CSS between sites.

Comment: @Laurel, are you referring to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321784/464709)? I hope that will aim towards the best result, globally. For instance, the question of how to distinguish links is probably part of that process, and underlining was chosen for a reason way back at first, so I'm curious to see the end result.

Comment: The post I'm remembering had pictures of links on several sites, both visited and unvisited, and I think it may be on MSE. It's related to that one, for sure.

Answer (score 5):

This is [my fault](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321731/241211), at least partly. I didn't realize so much would change, but I do appreciate being able to distinguish the numbers and strings.

Comment: Don't be too hard with yourself -- you're only responsible for the feature request, not for the implementation of the solution.

Comment: Yeah, don't fret. Who knew the dev team were even capable of rolling out changes <6-8 weeks?

Comment: Since you work on this issue, I'll repeat a relevant comment under the question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please Not world-shattering either way, but if there's a better approach that does customize per language, perhaps worth a look (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 2):

Don't give us amazing new color sets just to revert them the day after. It is not *right*.

That's what drug dealers do, but at least they'll sell you the stuff later.

**Now I want the new colors**, 
now I have a *need* I didn't know to have.

Damn.

[image]

Comment: We'll revisit the issue again. This is more of a temporary fix. When we revisit it again, we'll share it with the community to gather feedback first though.

Comment: For the records: Java / JSP / XML / Javascript highlightings were great, IMHO (Eclipse user)