# Why have strings within certain language-syntax code blocks gone green?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting, code

Strings in certain languages used to be a browny-redish colour. They're now green:

```js
// JavaScript
"Hello, world"
```

```php
// PHP
"Hello, world"
```

```cpp
// C++
"Hello, world"
```

I'm very used to green representing the colour of comments. If I search for "[comments in code](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=comments%20in%20code&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1n53_ta7MAhWHbRQKHR_aC4IQ_AUIBigB#)" on Google Images, the vast majority of the top results are all green. Likewise, searching for "[strings in code](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=comments%20in%20code&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1n53_ta7MAhWHbRQKHR_aC4IQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=strings%20in%20code)" gives a lot of results which have a browny-redish colour, just like SO used to use. It feels a bit weird looking at code with green strings.

Why are strings now green?

Comment: ... because of *improvements*  .... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321826/revert-new-syntax-colouring

Comment: [New Styles? New shade of green for accepted answers? It's not easy... being green](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321419)